# WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload is not working in augmented reality app on android phone using unity

Tags: android, augmented-reality, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build an augmented reality app and in that app i want some prefabs to load dynamically. So that with some 3d model prefabs on unity store i created myasset.unity3d . I am using WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload to download that unity3d file and using it.

When i am debugging in my laptop the file is downloading and i am using it as i want but when i add build in and try it on android phone download is not happening.

The code i am using to download is

```
IEnumerator DownloadAndCache() {
         while (!Caching.ready)
             yield return null;

         string bundleURL = "http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cf-export/sofa.unity3d";

         www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (bundleURL, 1);
         yield return www;

         Debug.Log (www.assetBundle);

         AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
 }
```

So please help me .

i also tried other way of doing it but still i did not succeed

```
IEnumerator Start () {
    WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (BundleURL, 1);
    yield return www;
    AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
    AssetBundleRequest request = bundle.LoadAssetAsync (AssetName, typeof(GameObject));
    yield return request;
    GameObject obj = request.asset as GameObject;
    Instantiate (obj);
    bundle.Unload(false);
    www.Dispose();
}
```

The above two methods are working in when testing in unity IDE but if i build using android and install it in android device its not working. I gave internet access to app while building

I printed the error using a text in mobile and please check the screen shot attached below
[image]

the first error text is www (variable for downloading) and second is www.error ( actual error). i did not get what that error meant. So please help me

Comment: is not happening or is slower? What I download in 2 sec in editor can take 2,3 or even 10 sec on device.

Comment: i waited for 10 minutes but it is not downloading @fafase

Comment: you are checking for Caching.ready but you start the loading after. Or are you starting elsewhere? You should check that it is not stuck there.

Comment: even tried removing while loop but still its not working @fafase

Comment: How are you calling the coroutine? You using StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache()); right?

Comment: @fafase please check edited part even that is not working for me

Comment: @fafase : can you check the error screen shot and let me know any information about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is asset bundle version is not sync with app version. So while making asset bundle i added small code which made my code working. To make Asset bundle my code is

```
using UnityEditor;

public class CreateAssetBundles
{
    [MenuItem ("Assets/Build AssetBundles")]
    static void BuildAllAssetBundles ()
    {
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles ("Assets/AssetBundles", BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.Android);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use AssetBuundle for Mobile platform:

1. While creating AssetBundle it **must be platform specific**. For Android use following Script to create AssetBundle. put it inside **"Editor"**

   ```
    using UnityEngine;
       using System.Collections;
       using UnityEditor;
       public class ExportAssetBundles : Editor {
           [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundle")]
           static void ExportResource()
           {
               string path = "Assets/AssetBundle/myAssetBundle.unity3d";
               Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(Object), SelectionMode.DeepAssets);
               BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Selection.activeObject, selection, path,
                                              BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies
                                            | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets,BuildTarget.Android);
           }
       }
   ```

   2. Then Create folder **"AssetBundle" inside Asset**

      When you create Assetbundle the **AssetBundle.unity3d** file will store inside this folder

   ---

   Now you need to use Created Assetbundle at runtime. For this,

   1. Write a script AssetBundleAugmenter

      ```
      public class AssetBundleAugmenter : MonoBehaviour {

      public string AssetName;
      public int Version;
      private GameObject mBundleInstance = null;
      private bool mAttached = false;
      void Start() {
          StartCoroutine(DownloadAndCache());

      }
      // Update is called once per frame
      IEnumerator DownloadAndCache() {
          while(!Caching.ready)
              yield return null;
          //you can use remote URL like: www.arprabhu.com/assetBundle OR Local URL
          // example URL of file on PC filesystem (Windows)
          // string bundleURL = "file:///D:/Unity/AssetBundles/MyAssetBundle.unity3d";
          // example URL of file on Android device SD-card

          string bundleURL = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("/mnt/sdcard/filepath.txt");
          Debug.Log ("Asset Loaded");
          using (WWW www = WWW .LoadFromCacheOrDownload(bundleURL, Version)) {
              yield return www;
              if (www .error != null)
                  throw new UnityException("WWW Download had an error: " + www .error);
              AssetBundle bundle = www .assetBundle;

              if (AssetName == "")
                  Instantiate(bundle.mainAsset);
              else
                  Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(AssetName));
              // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
              bundle.Unload(false);

          }
      }}
      ```
2. Attach this Script to Empty GameObject in your Scene

---

Congrats!, you are ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking your androidManifest.xml for the permission to connect to external servers.
Then, if everything seems alright and still doesn't work, my advice is to download the Device Console plugin for the Unity Editor, which is a really nice way to access the internal Android Debugger.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/44935

Or if you're truly brave: use `logcat` within the terminal...

Comment: can you check the error screen shot and let me know any information about the error @Tiziano Coroneo

Comment: It doesn't add any useful information to understand what is going on here, just use logcat to get a more verbose error message